# Cannot access a closed file in ASP.Net (saving files in zip file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, zip, dotnetzip

I got this error "Cannot access a closed file" when I save more than one file in zip.
This is the code. Error at `zip.Save(NewZipPath);`

```
internal static string UpdateZipFile(string PdfPath, string ZipPath, 
                    string NewZipPath, string docPath)
{
    try
    {
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ZipPath))
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(PdfPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(docPath);

        FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
        {
        zip.AddEntry(FI.FullName, fs);
        }

        // Error at this line if more than one
        // files in above directory.
        zip.Save(NewZipPath);

        fs.Close();
        fs.Dispose();

        return "- ZIP Generated Successfully !";
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Full exception

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
   at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
   at System.IO.FileStream.get_Length()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.SetInputAndFigureFileLength(Stream& input)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry._WriteEntryData(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry._EmitOne(Stream outstream)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
   at RideShare.Utility.UpdateZipFile(String PdfPath, 
String ZipPath, String NewZipPath, String docPath) in
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of DotNetZip are you using? This [might be fixed in a new version](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/10489).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that the use of the stream "FS" is tangled up. You can spend time trying to untangle it, or you can use the simpler "AddFiles" method:

Search for "Create a zip containing all the files in a folder." at

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples

Answer (score 0):

the `exception` happens because `AddEntry` uses the `FileStram` and after it is finished with the `FileStream` it closes it automatically.. so it is closed during `Save` after the first file... when there is one file it is ok - but your code adds the same FileStream `fs` for every file... not sure that this is what you really want... I think you would want to open one separate stream per file you add via `AddEntry`...

change your code to:

```
foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
    {
    zip.AddFile(FI.FullName);
    }
```

OR replace the `foreach` loop by

```
zip.AddFiles((from FI in Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) select FI.FullName).ToArray());
```